# Merge Table Row Values to Header of Another Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

---

### Table 1

```
id   |  Field           | Values        
----------------------------------------
1    | 'Field01'        |Name           
2    | 'Field02'        |Age  
3    | 'Field03'        |Gender  
4    | 'Field04'        |Qualification
```

---

### Table 2

```
id   |  Field01  | Field02 |Field03 |Field04
----------------------------------------
1    | Ajay      |18       |Male    |Bsc

2    | Arun      |19       |Male    |BA  
3    | Aruna     |18       |Female  |Bsc
```

---

### The OutPut Format is:

```
id   |  Name     | Age     |Gender  |Qualification
----------------------------------------
1    | Ajay      |18       |Male    |Bsc

2    | Arun      |19       |Male    |BA  
3    | Aruna     |18       |Female  |Bsc
```

Comment: why not you try it like,
 SELECT id, Field01 AS 'Name' .. FROM Table2

Comment: I Know this format Vijay. I have an More Fields Field01...Field75... Can i have an First Table Value Field is Header of Second table List...

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem for which you are asking for help?  Is it that you are getting SQL errors or that you have no idea where to start on a solution?

Comment: I don't have an Idea Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450125/replacing-column-names-in-a-query-with-values-in-a-lookup/25450892#25450892) where I answered a similar question on Stack Overflow.

You can do it with dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @fieldName varchar(32), @title varchar(32)
DECLARE @sql_cmd varchar(512)
SET @sql_cmd='SELECT id, '

DECLARE sql_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Field, Values FROM table1 ORDER BY id

OPEN sql_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor INTO @fieldName, @Title

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql_cmd = @sql_cmd + @fieldName + ' AS ' + @Title + ', '

    FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor
    INTO @fieldName, @Title
END;

CLOSE sql_cursor
DEALLOCATE sql_cursor

SET @sql_cmd = SUBSTRING(@sql_cmd,0,LEN(@sql_cmd)-2) + ' FROM table2'
EXEC(@sql_cmd)
```

Comment: This suggestion is Working accurately- Thank You!

Comment: In this cursor Convert to Linq Is Possible?

Comment: Do you consider calling a stored procedure? [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures) and [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/using-linq-with-stored-procedures) might help you get there. If you really want to bring it to LINQ, you can transform it into a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a Really Bad Design.  Reusable columns will lead you into a world of pain.  Amend the design to use normalised entities with properly-named attributes.  That said, I acknowledge that there may be nothing you personally can do about this schema.

Since this change is just about applying better labels to an existing resultset, can you get the presentation layer - GUI or reporting tool - to apply them?

As a last resort I can think of one SQL based implementation.  Apply an [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to the Table2.  This will give:

```
1,Field01,Ajay
1,Field02,18
1,Field03,Male
...
3,Field03,Female
3,Field04,Bsc
```

Join this to Table 1 to get

```
1,Field01,Ajay,Name
1,Field02,18,Age
1,Field03,Male,Gender
...
3,Field03,Female,Gender
3,Field04,Bsc,Qualification
```

Next `PIVOT` that omitting the "Fieldxx" column and you will have your desired output.